# API returns a html error response instead of json string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use "http://api.irkfdb.in/facts/random" as a get request from a nodejs program but instead I get a HTML page stating "Whoops, looks like something went wrong.".

Below is a my nodejs code. Is there something that I am missing?

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

function test() {
    let url = "http://api.irkfdb.in/facts/random";
    let request = http.get(url, function(response) {
        let body = "";
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            try {
                console.log(body);
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        })
    });
}
test();
```

I have also attached body variable content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <style>
            /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */
            html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}
            html { background: #eee; padding: 10px }
            img { border: 0; }
            #sf-resetcontent { width:970px; margin:0 auto; }
                        .sf-reset { font: 11px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333 }
            .sf-reset .clear { clear:both; height:0; font-size:0; line-height:0; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix:after { display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:inline-block; }
            .sf-reset * html .clear_fix { height:1%; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:block; }
            .sf-reset, .sf-reset .block { margin: auto }
            .sf-reset abbr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help; }
            .sf-reset p { font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#868686; padding-bottom:20px }
            .sf-reset strong { font-weight:bold; }
            .sf-reset a { color:#6c6159; cursor: default; }
            .sf-reset a img { border:none; }
            .sf-reset a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset em { font-style:italic; }
            .sf-reset h1, .sf-reset h2 { font: 20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif }
            .sf-reset .exception_counter { background-color: #fff; color: #333; padding: 6px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; float: left; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .exception_title { margin-left: 3em; margin-bottom: 0.7em; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .exception_message { margin-left: 3em; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .traces li { font-size:12px; padding: 2px 4px; list-style-type:decimal; margin-left:20px; }
            .sf-reset .block { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px 28px; margin-bottom:20px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .sf-reset .block_exception { background-color:#ddd; color: #333; padding:20px;
                border-top-left-radius: 16px;
                border-top-right-radius: 16px;
                border-top:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
                overflow: hidden;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .sf-reset a { background:none; color:#868686; text-decoration:none; }
            .sf-reset a:hover { background:none; color:#313131; text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset ol { padding: 10px 0; }
            .sf-reset h1 { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 15px 28px; margin-bottom: 20px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
                    <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">
                <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>

            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you please help what is going wrong with my code.

Comment: Can reproduce. Using a browser or command-line tool to make this request produces a JSON body, while OP's `node` code yields this error

Comment: @slezica: If I use the same url `http://api.irkfdb.in/facts/random` in browser I get proper json response, but with nodejs code it gives out html error response

Comment: Same here.  I sent request with Node.js (not OP code) and it's getting a 500 response.  Maybe it's expecting a header of some sort?

Comment: Their API docs say nothing: http://irkfdb.in/api-docs/

Comment: A quick test via http://web-sniffer.net/ suggest that this API expects a User-Agent request header to be present. It seems to be fine with whatever you select in the User Agent drop-down there - expect "none". So add a User-Agent header to your request, and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @CBroe you should post that as an answer :)

Comment: the user-agent request header as mandatory param has been relaxed it seems

Answer (score 0):

Like @CBroe pointed out in the comments, a request header is probably necessary. Specifically a `user-agent` is likely based on what he found.

A decent solution is to opt for a small package that has some sane defaults, like `node-fetch`.

*Caveat: this uses async/await features of the Node versions 7 and up, just remove those keywords and then invoke resp.json().then(json => ...) if you don't have nodejs 7 or 8*

`npm install node-fetch`

```
'use strict';

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const url = 'http://api.irkfdb.in/facts/random';

fetch(url, { method: 'GET' }).then(async resp => {

  let json = await resp.json();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

#### Edit

If you can [contact the api authors](http://irkfdb.in/contact/) I would tell them about this. It is likely their framework or their code is explicitly requiring something that most tools (curl included) just do by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#custom-http-headers) module, with custom http headers to add "User-Agent", as pointed by @CBroe

```
'use strict';

const request = require('request');

function test() {
    let url = "http://api.irkfdb.in/facts/random";
    var headers = { 
        'User-Agent': 'Request'
    };
    request.get({ url: url, headers: headers }, function (error, response, body) {
        // your callback body
        console.log(body);
    });
}
test();
```